# How to seed in relation table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create some app like hockey teams ranks and matches. I think in matches table I must to have two foreign keys(first_team_id and second_team_id).I did it in migrations (create_mathes_table):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('first_team_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('second_team_id');
            $table->foreign('first_team_id')->references('id')->on('team');
            $table->foreign('second_team_id')->references('id')->on('team');
            $table->date('match_date');
        });
    }
```

and I have that relation in Team model(Many-To-Many):

```
public function matches()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Match');
    }
```

And I already seeding in Team table but I don't know how to seed in relation table Match with two foreign keys,I seeded in Team table like this:
**Seeder**:

```
public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Team::class,11)->create();
    }
```

**Factory**:

```
<?php
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
$factory->define(App\Team::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    $team_example = ['Dinamo','Schacter','Zorya','Stal','Vorskla','Olimpik','Mariupol','Zvezda','Karpaty','Chernomorets','Veres'];
    return [
        'name' => $faker->unique()->randomElement($team_example),
        'score' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 15)
    ];
});
```

Comment: What's type of tournament ? is it Knock out or League type ?

Comment: Can you show your model factory for `Match` as well?

Comment: I can't build factory for Match model, it's a question

Answer (score 1):

Define the factory for `Match` first.

```
$factory->define(App\Match::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        ///
    ];
});
```

And then try following:

```
factory(App\Match::class, 11)->create([
    'first_team_id' => factory(App\Team::class)->create()->id,
    'second_team_id' => factory(App\Team::class)->create()->id,
]);
```

Comment: I tried your answer but now I have overflow exception when do "artisan db:seed"

Comment: Which overflow exception.